# Error in installing mysql using macports

Tags: mysql, macos, port, macports

I am a bit new Mac. I tried installing mysql5 using the following link:

http://matthewcarriere.com/2008/04/02/installing-mysql-on-mac-os-x-leopard-using-macports/

When I tried running the following:

```
sudo /opt/local/bin/mysqld_safe5 &
```

I got this:

```
[2] 59079
ps: No user named 'axww'
130911 13:35:11 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/local/var/db/mysql5
```

After this, I tried the following:

```
mysqladmin5 -u root -p ping
```

I got the following error:

```
mysqladmin5: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That article is obviously a bit antiquated. The modern preferred way to start a daemon installed with MacPorts is by using the `port load` command.

```
sudo port load mysql5-server
```

Stop it by using `port unload`.